# When creating a subscription, if the destinations part is not a list, it will panic

Tags: database, time-series, cnosdb

When creating a subscription, if the destinations part is not a list, it will panic.

I create a  SUBSCRIPTION as follow,

```
 
public ❯ CREATE SUBSCRIPTION test ON public DESTINATIONS ALL "127.0.0.1:8903 127.0.0.1:8904";

Query took 0.018 seconds.
public ❯
```

it was succeed, but when i check log

the cnosdb log as follow:

```
2023-11-07T14:53:19.447137000+08:00  INFO coordinator::subscription: Subscription sender starting, destinations: ["127.0.0.1:8903 127.0.0.1:8904"]
2023-11-07T14:53:19.447202000+08:00  INFO coordinator::subscription: Subscription sender starting, destinations: ["127.0.0.1:8903 127.0.0.1:8904"]
2023-11-07T14:53:19.447464000+08:00  INFO coordinator::subscription: Subscription sender starting, destinations: ["127.0.0.1:8903 127.0.0.1:8904"]
2023-11-07T14:53:19.447308000+08:00  INFO coordinator::subscription: Subscription sender starting, destinations: ["127.0.0.1:8903 127.0.0.1:8904"]
The application panicked (crashed).
Message:  called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: InvalidUri(InvalidUriChar)
Location: coordinator/src/subscription.rs:235

  ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ BACKTRACE ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
                                ⋮ 10 frames hidden ⋮                              
  11: coordinator::subscription::SubscriptionService::send_to_destination::{{closure}}::h2e4c96d3d075bd34
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  12: tokio::runtime::task::raw::poll::h6232cf87137989d3
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  13: tokio::runtime::scheduler::multi_thread::worker::Context::run_task::h47d6f1ce70b80ea6
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  14: tokio::runtime::scheduler::multi_thread::worker::run::h01f7d052d389905f
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  15: tokio::runtime::task::raw::poll::h20df62bfae0681f8
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  16: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace::h0cb9a5736f1dc2ab
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  17: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once{{vtable.shim}}::h2c7aec67e606f82e
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  18: std::sys::unix::thread::Thread::new::thread_start::h5343322b5f9311e3
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>
  19: __pthread_joiner_wake<unknown>
      at <unknown source file>:<unknown line>

Run with COLORBT_SHOW_HIDDEN=1 environment variable to disable frame filtering.
Run with RUST_BACKTRACE=full to include source snippets.
```